# Dynamically change the position of UITableViewCell in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a custom tableView in my application. In this custom cell, i have one textfield. When user taps this Textfield, then keyboard will appear. At this time i want to change the position of that selected cell in Tableview. Herewith i attached a snapshot of actual output and i attached my expected snapshot also.

Image 1 - Normal screen, it contains Custom UITableView.

[image]

When i select the textfield(marked as red circle in above image), keyboard is appeared like in Image 2.

[image]

But i except to change the position of selected textfield to upside of the keyboard, like in Image 3.

[image]

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding third party library? It is quite simple.

Comment: change(increase) the UITableViewCell's height temporarily when the keyboard is open, and when keyboard closes, decrease the cell's height.

Comment: The right solution is given by @cekisakurek, or you can implement the logic same as `TPKeyboardAvoiding`. Its really easy to use.

Comment: change the tableView Offset.

Comment: @cekisakurek - Thanks for your comments. Really it solved my issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only a textField in your code, the easy way is probably:

-Add a observer to the keyboard appearance:

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardAppear) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

-And its method:

```
  -(void)keyboardAppear
{
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, yOfYourTextField)];
}
```

If you have several textField, the best option is implement the delegate to all this textField and its delegate scroll the tableView.

```
 -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, textField.tag * 40 -70) animated:YES];
//.. more if you need
}
```

And If you use a UITableViewController instead of a tableView inside a UIViewController the scroll behavior is automatic.

Comment: Why would you use tags? You know, the text field has a frame and that frame has its y position - and it can be easily converted to screen coordinates. Code involving tags and magic numbers is bad code. Also, you have to work with keyboard height if you want to center the text field correctly.

Comment: It´s the other project, I use tags to save in the textField the indexPath.row, and this is the way to know what cell I need to show. This is an old example of a iPad project in landscape, I didn't the keyboard size, but you are wright and probably Hi need it, depends on the kind of reference Hi will create between textField and its position in the tableView.